# How to tell if a Google Drive URL contains an image

Tags: url, google-drive-api

Is there anyway to tell from a Google drive url whether is an image? They use a word "file" to describe images, but they use that for zip files and others

https://drive.google.com/**file**/d/0BMvQwrQ3VuRWIIcVUyRjQ/edit?usp=sharing

is there any else that says it's specifically an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to look at the mimeType in the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files).